# Autofilter column by number of digits at end of string

Tags: excel, vba

How would I filter out all the values in a column that end with 8 digits?

```
       H
1 Description
2 7825434583090234927383811GEORGEBOYYY12345678
3 8923459283409192043290482CANTELOPEZZZ23456789
4 TH 1264045 Actuals
5 18723892734598298592348592BILLYBOB34567891
```

My desired output would be:

```
       H
1 Description
2 7825434583090234927383811GEORGEBOYYY12345678
3 8923459283409192043290482CANTELOPEZZZ23456789
5 18723892734598298592348592BILLYBOB34567891
```

Because those are the rows where the last 8 values are digits.

I've tried using the autofilter ends with:

```
With ActiveSheet.Range("H:H").CurrentRegion
   .AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:= _
    "=*{1-9}8", Operator:=xlAnd
End With
```

I am unsure of the correct notation.

Comment: Do you have to use Autofilter, or could you use an alternative method?

Comment: @dwirony it can be an alternative method, as long as it ends up with the correct filtered rows. Autofilter is just what I was experimenting with because I'm not too skilled at Excel

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Right` and `IsNumeric` to determine which rows don't end in 8 numbers. Just modify the amount of rows accordingly:

```
Sub hidetherows()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Long
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Rename the sheet here
lastrow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To lastrow
    If Not IsNumeric(Right(Range("H" & i).Value, 8)) Then
        Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! Unfortunately my last row is dynamic, is there a way to incorporate an unknown last row into this?

Comment: Sure is, let me rewrite it rq. Edited: Also changed the column to H since it looks like that's the one you're using.

Comment: thanks for your edit! I'll have to keep toying with it, I have 65000 rows of data and this may not be the most timely thing

Comment: @codeninja Interesting... I do remember this being an issue with manipulating large amounts of data... I believe the workaround that someone created was creating instead of hiding rows, creating a new sheet, pasting the desired values onto that sheet, then deleting the old sheet.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to VBA is using a Helper column.  Say your list is in column A, starting at `A2`.  You can do

```
=IF(ISERROR(NUMBERVALUE(RIGHT(A2,8))),"",A2)
```

and drag down. Then filter on that column, as there will be blanks where the last 8 digits aren't a number.

Comment: A great alternative to VBA!

Comment: @dwirony - It's weird though...I was trying what you did, essentially, by doing `=RIGHT(A2,8)`, then doing `=ISNUMBER()` on that result. For whatever reason, it was always returning `FALSE`.  Not sure why!

Comment: To avoid a helper column, you could use this same formula as an `Advanced Filter` criteria